# How to use mouse scroll to hide windows?

Tags: gnome, mouse, window-manager, mouse-scroll

I used to set the mouse scroll to hide the windows when scrolling on the title bar: alas, I can't remember how I did that...

Can you please tell me how to achieve it?

Comment: As far as you remember, can it be something compiz-related?

Comment: You can change the animation settings in compiz, but good ol' metacity has the shade feature (as does kwin as far as I know)

Comment: I was searching around compiz too, but as Nick said, it had only animation features.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're in luck! Just the other day I was trying to do this and found out how.

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the "Run Application" Dialog
2. Type in `gconf-editor` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Go to *apps* -> *gwd*
4. Double click on the `mouse_wheel_action` row
5. Type in `shade` as the value. Press okay and voila!

Comment: It is still working in 12.04! great!

Answer (score 5):

### For 12.10

Run this command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.gwd mouse-wheel-action "shade"
```

Alternatively, you can use [dconf-editor [image: Install dconf-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) to edit the settings.

Open `dconf-editor` and navigate to `org` → `compiz` → `gwd` and enter `shade` for `mouse-wheel-action`.

[image: dconf-tools]

Comment: Still works, as of 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Ubuntu-Tweak**. Here is how to install it :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Ubuntu-Tweak is a popular Ubuntu application that make it easier to config Ubuntu for everyone.

Here is a screenshot of the option in Ubuntu-Tweak (Titlebar mouse wheel action) :

[image: Ubuntu-Tweak Window Manager Settings]

Comment: Thank you, but I've already managed to set it up: besides, I prefer to use what the system already offers, without installing other packages.